# Protractor elementExplorer not working, repl not appearing on windows

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to get elementExplorer working.

I'm trying the following:

```
node node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor .\protractor.dev.conf.js --baseUrl http://angularjs.org --elementExplorer
```

with the following config

```
/// protractor.dev.conf.js

    exports.config = {
        // The address of a running selenium server.
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:54054/',

        // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
        capabilities: {
          'browserName': 'chrome',
          'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['show-fps-counter=true'],
            'binary' : 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\Application\\chrome.exe'
           } 
        },

        specs: ['specs/acceptance/**/*.js'],
        framework: 'mocha',
        onPrepare: 'specs/bootstrap-specs.js',
        mochaOpts: {
            reporter: "spec",
            debug : true,
            timeout : 4000
        }
    };
```

It loads chromium as expected but it doesnt redirect to http://angularjs.org and the repl never appears.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Note: I can execute normal tests fine

Thanks

I've added the --troubleshoot flag and get the following:

```
> DEBUG - Running with --troubleshoot DEBUG - Protractor version: 1.7.0
> DEBUG - Your base url for tests is http://angularjs.org Using the
> selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub DEBUG - WebDriver
> session successfully started with capabilities { caps_:    { platform:
> 'XP',
>      acceptSslCerts: true,
>      javascriptEnabled: true,
>      browserName: 'chrome',
>      chrome: { userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir25488_18232' },
>      rotatable: false,
>      locationContextEnabled: true,
>      mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
>      'webdriver.remote.sessionid': '06c7edae-15e9-4e9a-8293-91e2d5c4fe90',
>      version: '42.0.2310.0',
>      takesHeapSnapshot: true,
>      cssSelectorsEnabled: true,
>      databaseEnabled: false,
>      handlesAlerts: true,
>      browserConnectionEnabled: false,
>      nativeEvents: true,
>      webStorageEnabled: true,
>      applicationCacheEnabled: false,
>      takesScreenshot: true } } Starting debugger agent. Debugger listening on port 5858
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely related to https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1822, which is a windows problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've just rolled back to version 1.6.1 and it worked.